# Can't understand why the DP Subset Sum algorithm is not polynomial

Tags: complexity-theory, terminology, np-complete, dynamic-programming, polynomial-time

I can not understand why the dynamic programming algorithm for the Subset Sum, is not polynomial.

Even though the sum to find 'T' is greater than the total sum of the 'n' elements of the set , the number of iterations is always (T * n) and not exponential  I'm not understanding it.

The algorithm always do 'n*T' comparisons, and writes in the matrix only 'n*T' times...I'm missing something and I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that you have to take into account the binary encoding of numbers.  The input size $m$ is really the total number of bits, so if your instance is $a_1,\ldots, a_n, T$, then $m = \log T + \sum_{i\in [n]} \log a_i$.

In particular, $T$ can be super-polynomial in $m$, so the dynamic programming algorithm's runtime can be made super-polynomial as well, since it needs to take one step to build every cell of its table. (The quantity $nT$ can be made $\Omega(2^{m/3})$ for example.)

On the other hand, when all the numbers in the instance are restricted to be "small" (i.e., polynomially bounded in $m$), the SUBSET-SUM becomes tractable.  (Notice that the usual reduction from 3SAT has very large numbers in it.)

A problem is [strongly NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_NP-complete) when it remains NP-Complete even when all the numeric values are polynomial in the input length. SUBSET-SUM isn't (it's called weakly NP-Complete).

The kind of running time that is polynomial in the numeric values in the input is known as *pseudo-polynomial*.

Comment: The buzzword of note here is [pseudo-polynomial time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time). One has to leave behind comfortable RAM models (with uniform costs) and really consider the TM model (with logarithmic cost model).

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity but, what exactly turns to be exponential...in all problems instances coudl be very large too...I mean n*T could be large ¿and? I don't understand...

Comment: For $nT$ to be polynomial in $m$, $T$ has to be polynomial in $m$.  But since $T$ contributes only $\log T$ bits to $m$, this isn't necessarily true.  For concreteness, consider the case where $T$ is an $m/2$ bit number and see what happens to the number of entries written in the matrix.

Comment: Thank you, Louis. I don't see it, I'm missing something. If T is m/2 bit, the number of entries in the matrix is the same n*T, I have an n*T matrix, no matter the bits. In the straightforward algorithm for addition the number of the entries could be large too m/2 bit, and it isn't pseudo polinomial. Why? I'm lost.

Comment: What you are missing is that a $k$-bit number can be as large as $2^k - 1$.

Comment: Ok, ok, I think I understand now so...my computer works with a matrix n*T, but if T is large, my computer must work with a matrix whose indices are very large in bits...so we are traslating the time problem to the memory problem, aren't we?

Comment: If $T = 2^{m/2}$ then even looking at every entry in your table takes time super-polynomial in $m$.

Comment: @Raphael I'm not sure the term _pseudo-polynomial_ qualifies as a _buzzword_ ...

Comment: @Pedro What you're missing is that you can't just pick a variable, call it $n$, observe that the running time is polynomial in $n$ and declare the algorithm to be polynomial time. Polynomial time means that the running time of the algorithm is bounded by a polynomial function of the input length in bits, which is called "$m$" in this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to think about it which may be easier to understand: If we double $T$, we need one more bit to represent it, and $T$ is part of the input, so the input size increases by one bit. However, the run time doubles, and we can keep doing this and the run time will double each time while the input size will increase by one each time.

We measure the complexity of algorithms *by considering the run time as a function of the input size*, and in this example, the run time grows exponentially *with respect to the input size*, so we know that the run time cannot be polynomial.

Comment: I'm probably mistaken but this last comment seems to imply that P!=NP. Could you elaborate on what you mean by "...in this example, the run time grows exponentially with respect to the input size, so we know that the run time cannot be polynomial"

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm is exponential in the size of the input because of the assumption that integers are represented in binary. The running time is $O(T \cdot n)$, where $T$ is the integer (sum) and $n$ is the size of the set. Since $T$ is - typically and realistically - represented in binary, $T$ is represented by at least $O(log_2 T)$ bits`*`. So it takes $O(log_2 T)$ time to read this bit-vector sequentially. In the DP algorithm, you have to consider all values (sums) from $1$ to $T$ (assuming $T$ is positive); *this is exponential in the length of $T$*. To see this, note that:

$k = log_2 T$
$T = 2^{k}$

So if you have a bit-vector that is $b$ bits long, the largest number you can represent is approximately $2^b$; a number exponential in $b$.

**Example**
The maximum value of a $32$ bit signed integer is $T = 2^{31} - 1$. In order to read this bit-vector sequentially you have to read $32$ bits. But if you want to, say, make an array of length $T$, this would yield an array of length $T = 2^{31} - 1 = 2,147,483,647$. To construct the array would also take $T$ time.

**Alternative representation**
You could represent integers in unary, which means that the length of the representation of the integer is equal to the value of the integer. Then you could say that the running time of the algorithm is polynomial. But this is of course not an improvement. Algorithms like this, which are polynomial in the *numeric* value of the input, are said to run in **pseudo-polynomial time**.

---

`*` Typically, integers are stored in a fixed size representation, e.g. $32$ bits or $64$ bits. I also use big-oh notation to omit the details of how to exactly get the length of the representation of the integer, or the minimum length that would be needed in order to represent an integer in binary, since I feel that it might lead to a lot of details that don't help convey the overall idea.

Comment: So the problem is only the array, isn't it? Becouse the memory it consumed...Is that? I don't think that are the sum from 1 to T, becouse that's polinomial, isn't it?

Comment: @Pedro I don't think I understand what you mean. It is not important if what we are doing is to construct an array, or if we are looping; the point is in the fact that we have to iterate from $1$ to $T$, while $T$ is given to us as a bit-vector (so if $T$ is represented as $32$ bits, $T$ might be as large as $2^{31} - 1$, which means we have to iterate from $1$ to $2^{31} - 1$.

Comment: For that matter; if you have, say, a DP algorithm that constructs and array of size $T$ and iterates through it in order to solve some problem, that would mean that the *space complexity* of the algorithm is $O(T)$. Maybe it was the distinction between space complexity and run time complexity that you were getting at?

Comment: Oh...so If we iterate in a For...next from 1 to N , we are really iterating from 1 to 2^31?

Comment: ^ Yes, if $N = 2^{31}$. Meanwhile, $N$ is represented by only $32$ bits.

Comment: Yes, I wonder if with DP, we are moving our run time complexity dificulty to a Space complexity dificulti..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14381/discussion-between-guildenstern-and-pedro)