# How approximable is time-bounded Kolmogorov Complexity?

Tags: optimization, approximation, kolmogorov-complexity

Given a Turing Complete Language, the optimization problem would be: Given inputs x and S, where x is a finite binary string and S is a limit on steps, find the shortest program in that TC language that outputs the string x in less than or equal to S steps. (With S being in unary.)

My question is how approximable this definition of time-bounded KC is in terms of the NPO classes such as PTAS, APX, log APX, and so on.

I've been searching and have only been able to find info on KC itself and little info on resource-bounded KC as a decision or optimization problem.

Comment: Is S in [unary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system)? ​ (If no, then the problem is not obviously in NPO.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Steps can't be negative so it's greater than or equal to 1.

Comment: What's the significance of it being in unary?

Comment: See [this question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/24484/12859) and its answers. ​ ​

Comment: Very interesting distinction, for the purpose of my question then yes S is in unary.

Comment: Well, if [PRGs](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/research/OWFtoPRG-abs.html) exist then for all positive constants c and functions f in [ω](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations)(log), distinguishing [shortest_length < n^c] from [output_length < f(input_length)+shortest_length] is infeasible. ​ ​